# Google maps API correct countries names list

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hello i need correct countries names list when use google api. Google found the country by name. For example use this script: `jsfiddle:`http://jsfiddle.net/9F7Gp/10/

In input write country name and google api found it. I need country names list when use google, somebody have it? Cannot use list from wikipedia or other source because not find a few countries like a "Democratic Republic of Congo", need correct name then use google

Comment: http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2countrySelectList.html

Comment: "Democratic Republic of the Congo" works for me.  If you have a question on the name of a country that is understood by the geocoder, reverse geocode a point in that country and look for the returned result's long_name (with the types "political" and "country" `{"long_name": "Democratic Republic of the Congo","short_name": "CD","types": ["country","political"]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Democratic Republic of the Congo" works for me.

A general method to determine the name of a country that is understood by the geocoder, would be to reverse geocode a point in that country and look for the returned result's long_name (with the types "political" and "country"

```
{
  "long_name": "Democratic Republic of the Congo",
  "short_name": "CD",
  "types": [
    "country",
    "political"
  ]
}
```